# Citrix Access to single Website

Tags: azure, web, citrix

We have an Azure hosted web application and I've been asked about Citrix clients  where they don't have direct access to a web browser in their Citrix desktop.

Is it possible to setup a web application in Citrix that points to a website so they can use the application but cannot surf away from the application i.e say they get a browser window with no address bar?

If the above is possible are there any gotchas that the website needs to cater for given Citrix usage.

Many thanks

Si

Answer (score 0):

Sure, they should have a browser published as a resource.
It is possible to publish a browser with an argument that would navigate directly to your site upon launching.